# Unstack a dataframe into a variable number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a datframe consisting of top ranked model features for each id from a machine learning model. The data is sorted by id, and then by the model feature's performance statistic like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    'feature_name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'F', 'C'],
    'feature_value': [10, -6, 0.3, 100, 11, -2, -0.2, 11, 0.25],
    'performance_statistic': [0.009, -0.001, 0.030, 0.002, -0.001, -0.007, 0.034, 0.007, -0.015]
})
print(df)

   id feature_name  feature_value  performance_statistic
0   1            A          10.00                  0.009
1   1            B          -6.00                 -0.001
2   2            C           0.30                  0.030
3   2            D         100.00                  0.002
4   2            A          11.00                 -0.001
5   2            B          -2.00                 -0.007
6   3            E          -0.20                  0.034
7   3            F          11.00                  0.007
8   3            C           0.25                 -0.015
```

In the real data there are a couple more columns and nearly 200k rows. For each id there is a variable number of features. I want to unstack this dataframe into a wide format so that there is a single row per id and column for the top model feature/value/statistic, the second feature/value/statistic, and so on, like so:

```
   id feature_name1 feature_name2 feature_name3 feature_name4  feature_value1  \
0   1             A             B           NaN           NaN            10.0   
1   2             C             D             A             B             0.3   
2   3             E             F             C           NaN            -0.2   

   feature_value2  feature_value3  feature_value4  performance_statistic1  \
0              -6             NaN             NaN                   0.009   
1             100           11.00            -2.0                   0.030   
2              11            0.25             NaN                   0.034   

   performance_statistic2  performance_statistic3  performance_statistic4  
0                  -0.001                     NaN                     NaN  
1                   0.002                  -0.001                  -0.007  
2                   0.007                  -0.015                     NaN
```

My problem is that each id has a (mostly) different feature set and variable number of features each time a model is run, resulting in a variable number of columns in the final dataframe. My current strategy is to use a function to unstack one row at a time and rename all of the columns, and then merge all of the results into a single dataframe. Here is the function and the code for a single column:

```
# Function to unstack columns
def fn(x):
    vals = x.values.ravel()
    return pd.DataFrame(
        [vals],
        columns=[f"value {i}" for i in range(1, vals.shape[0] + 1)],
    )

# Unstack each feature and rename accounting for variation in number of explainers
feature_name = (
    df[['id', 'feature_name']].set_index("id")
    .groupby(level=0)
    .apply(fn)
    .reset_index()
    .drop(columns="level_1")
)

for i in (range(feature_name.shape[1]-1)):
    key = 'value '+ str(i+1)
    val = 'feature_name' + str(i+1)
    feature_name.rename(columns={key:val}, inplace=True)
```

This method works fine, but takes 10-12 minutes to run each time. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: `out = df.assign(col=df.groupby('id').cumcount().add(1)).pivot(index='id', columns='col') ; out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}') ; out = out.reset_index()`